# Update the value if same key of array or insert as new value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-5

I am making a minimalist eCommerce web application using laravel framework and I am a newbie.

What I am trying to achieve is when a product exists in the session, I want to update the quantity of that product when `Add to Cart` button is clicked. And if it doesn't exists in the session, I want to insert it in the session.

Code that I have tried so far:

```
public function store( $id ) {

    $product = Product::findOrFail( $id );

    if ( \Session::has( 'cart' ) && is_array( \Session::get('cart') ) ) {
        \Session::push('cart', ['product' => (int)$id, 'quantity' => 1 ]);
    } else {
        \Session::put('cart', ['product' => (int)$id, 'quantity' => 1 ]);
    }

    \Session::flash('added_product', 'Product Added in the cart');

    return \Redirect::back();
}
```

The result of the above code is:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "product" => 1
    "quantity" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "product" => 2
    "quantity" => 1
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "product" => 1
    "quantity" => 1
  ]
]
```

Desired Result is:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "product" => 1
    "quantity" => 2
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "product" => 2
    "quantity" => 1
  ]
]
```

Kindly help me out with this. Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**:

After Youssef Answer, I got the following result:

```
array:4 [▼
  "product" => 1
  "quantity" => 1
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "product" => 3
    "quantity" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "product" => 2
    "quantity" => 1
  ]
]
```

Comment: Sorry I just noticed what you are trying to do. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Okay.. Waiting for it..

Comment: OK, added a new answer for you

Comment: Can anybody please help me out ?

Comment: check with my latest edit, i think it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Laravel but i think you can just process the array like this:

```
public function store( $id ) {

    $product = Product::findOrFail( $id );

    if ( \Session::has( 'cart' ) && is_array( \Session::get('cart') ) ) {
        $cart = \Session::get('cart');
        $found = false;
        foreach($cart as $i=>$el)
        {
           if($el['product'] == $id)
           { 
             $cart[$i]['quantity']++;
             $found = true;
           }
        }
        if(!$found) {
          $cart[] = ['product' => $i, 'quantity' => 1];
        }
        \Session::put('cart', $cart);
    } else {
        \Session::put('cart', [['product' => (int)$id, 'quantity' => 1 ]]);
    }

    \Session::flash('added_product', 'Product Added in the cart');

    return \Redirect::back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the entry exists in the session you are creating and pushing a yet another item to the array which results in a duplicate result. You should probably change the if block to the following:

```
$value = Session::pull( 'cart', ['product' => int($id), 'quantity' => 0 ]);
$value['quantity'] += 1;
Session::put('cart', $value);
```

The `pull` method call will get you the cart value if it exists or create a new one if it doesn't exist (with quantity 0). It increments the quantity, which means it will rise by 1 if it's already there or set to 1 if it's the one you created in the `pull` call. The value is removed from session when you call `pull` so you will put back the new value into the session by calling `put`. Hope this gives a more concise code.

You can add array safety checks to the increment statement as: `array_key_exists('quantity')`